# Sums and Products of Borel measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

We say a function f is Borel measurable if for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) > \alpha \}$ is Borel.

If f, g are Borel measurable, then f+g is Borel measurable.

First since f and g are Borel measurable then $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) > \alpha \}$ and $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: g(x) > \alpha \}$.

So f+g being Borel measurable, then I need to prove that $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x)+g(x) > \alpha \}$ is Borel.

Isn't the last set just a union of  $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) > \alpha \}$ and $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: g(x) > \alpha \}$ which are individually Borel measurable (I've proven this).

Comment: $2+2 > 3$ but $2 < 3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Write $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x)+g(x) > \alpha \}$ as a countable union of sets easily seen to be Borel sets.

Comment: Does this follow from the fact that if we just assume that f(x) and g(x) are measurable, then:

$f(x) > c - g(x)$, thus we can find a $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(x) > q > c - g(x)$.  This is just $\{f(x) > q\} \cap \{q > c-g(x)\}$.  Take the union through all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Furthermore it's the countable union of Borel sets.  I believe each of those is already a Borel set.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to show first that $(f,g)$ is a Borel function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$ and then that, for every $\alpha$, $\{(u,v)\in\mathbb R^2\mid u+v>\alpha\}$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Probably not helpful for EMKA.

Comment: @GEdgar: What is the use of this comment of yours?