# Bounded variation implies Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation

Suppose that $f\colon[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function of bounded variation. Show that $f$ is Borel measurable.

I was wondering if I could get a hint.

Comment: Can you prove that a monotone function is Borel measurable?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro do you mean that the statement is wrong?

Comment: @Mathstupid: If you can prove that a monotone function is Borel measurable, then a BV function will also be Borel measurable, because [every BV measurable function is the algebraic (pointwise) difference of two monotone functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141338/13130) and [the difference of two Borel measurable functions is Borel measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66300/sums-and-products-of-borel-measurable-functions).

Comment: So do you have a source for proving that a monotone function is Borel measurable ?@DaveL.Renfro

Comment: [monotone + function + borel + measurable + site:math.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=monotone+function+borel+measurable+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 4):

You see that for $ f \in BV([a,b]) $ you can write $ f = g - h $ where $ g(x) = V^x_a(f) $ and $ h = g-f $ where both $g $ and $h$ are monotonically increasing hence have countably many discontinuities.